# Plot: Construct an Amoeba

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot an Amoeba, e.g we consider the polynomial `f(z, w) = 2 z - w + 1` and solve it explicitly , the solutions satisfy the equation `w = 2z + 1`, where $w,z\in \mathbb{C}$ under the map 
$$(Log|z|, Log|2z+1|)$$

So, I did the following:

```
ParametricPlot[{Log[Abs[r Exp[I s]]], Log[Abs[2 r Exp[I s] + 1]]}, {r, 0, 3}, {s, -π, π}]
```

I want to get the picture showed below, but the result has flaws -- I am not supposed to get those curves inside the region

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: When I run your code I don't get the green background or the lines inside the figure.

Comment: Fine with me too

Answer (score 5):

```
ParametricPlot[{Log[Abs[r*Exp[I*s]]], Log[Abs[2*r*Exp[I*s] + 1]]}, {r,
   0, 10}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[1]}, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

If you want to get the original pictue then:

```
ParametricPlot[{Log[Abs[r Exp[I s]]], Log[Abs[2 r Exp[I s] + 1]]}, {r,
   0, 3}, {s, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
 Background -> LightGreen, ImagePadding -> 15]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a few options to get rid of the plot-junk:

```
ParametricPlot[{Log[Abs[r Exp[I s]]], Log[Abs[2 r Exp[I s] + 1]]}, 
  {r, 0, 3}, {s, -π, π}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]