# Plotting a parameteric function

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I aim to plot the [amoeba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(mathematics)) of `f=x1^3 + x2^3 - 4 x1 x2 + 1` . Following [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85081/plot-construct-an-amoeba), I have solved `f==0` and tried to plot the log of the solutions. The output is presented on page thirteen of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.08663).

My current script, which does not show any output, reads

```
sol = Solve[x1^3 + x2^3 - 4 x1 x2 + 1 == 0, x2];
ParametricPlot[{Re[Log[ Abs[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. {x1 -> r*Exp[I*s]}]]], 
  Im[Log[ Abs[sol[[1, 1, 2]] /. {x1 -> r*Exp[I*s]}]]], 
  Re[Log[Abs[sol[[2, 1, 2]] /. {x1 -> r*Exp[I*s]}]]], 
  Im[Log[Abs[sol[[2, 1, 2]] /. {x1 -> r*Exp[I*s]}]]]}, {r, 0.5, 
  20}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[1]}, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

Do you have any suggestions for finding out where my errors are?

Comment: You have the wrong syntax for "ParametricPlot". Maybe you want to use "Plot3D"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

P[x1_, x2_] = x1^3 + x2^3 - 4 x1 x2 + 1;

sol = SolveValues[P[x1, x2] == 0, x2] // FullSimplify;

Row[plts = ParametricPlot[
     Evaluate[
      {Log[Abs[x1]], Log[Abs[#[[1]]]]} /. x1 -> r*Exp[I*s]],
     {r, 0, 3}, {s, -Pi, Pi},
     Axes -> False,
     BoundaryStyle -> None,
     PlotPoints -> 60,
     PlotRange -> All,
     PlotStyle -> Directive[#[[2]], Opacity[0.25]],
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     ImageSize -> 216] & /@
   Transpose[{sol, ColorData[97] /@ Range[3]}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[plts, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions work the same way

```
P2[x1_, x2_] = (-27 - 54 x2^3 + 4 x1^3 x2^5 - 27 x2^6)/x2^2;

sol2 = SolveValues[P2[x1, x2] == 0, x2];

Partition[
  plts2 = ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[
       {Log[Abs[x1]], Log[Abs[#[[1]]]]} /. x1 -> r*Exp[I*s]],
      {r, 0, 3}, {s, -Pi, Pi},
      Axes -> False,
      BoundaryStyle -> None,
      PlotPoints -> 70,
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotStyle -> Directive[#[[2]], Opacity[0.25]],
      AspectRatio -> 1,
      ImageSize -> 216] & /@
    Transpose[{sol2, ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@sol2]}],
  2] // Grid
```

[image]

```
Show[plts2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1)Thank you very much. This is great!

Comment: Do you know what I should do to get the plot when the output of `SolveValues` is not an expression but in the form of `Root[]`; for example, `(-27 - 54 x2^3 + 4 x1^3 x2^5 - 27 x2^6)/x2^2`?

Comment: Thank you also for the update.